# What is the customer id in the calendar resorce request?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

Hi i have been trying to get the resources from my calendar in google.
While checking the google support i found the following:

"https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/customerid/resources/calendars"

It was said that the above URL will help me to get the contents.

The customer id section is what confusion me? from where do i get the customer is? Even if it is from the admin panel, cane someone help me with the steps to get that?

Comment: Wrong api try this one https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: Hi @DaImTo , thank you for the reference. I did go through the code and it describes only to get the current events from the calendar where as what i need is to get the resources from the account.

Comment: Your topic states Google calendar API as is your tagging, your API end point is for the Directory admin API.  This is two different APIs.   Your question is unclear can you give us some more detail in what you are trying to achieve.   Include your code and any errors you are getting.  Ideally your question should include http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure 
I am sorry if my question was unclear. I will explain in detail. I have 3 users under my work account in google. I have a common calendar too. Currently i am using the google php library to sync all the data. I want to fetch the resources too especially the rooms from the calendar. So can you help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [Resources.calendars: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/list)

> customer
>   string
>   The unique ID for the customer's Google account. As an
>   account administrator, you can also use the my_customer alias to
>   represent your account's customer ID.

Unfortunately I don't have access to a domain account so I cant help you test it.  All of the information you need is in the documentation.

Comment: Yes 
This is what i was looking at. i am not sure where the my_customer is an alias or do we have such an alias somewhere in the admin console.
Any way thanks for the response. Do you have any other way of retrieving the resources?

Comment: Its probably a default thing kind of like using "me" in the other APIs its just means the current authenticated user.

Comment: I kind of wonder if you could do a user.list  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list  then loop though the results of that sending customer Id returned by that request against your resources.calendars list which should in theory give you a list of calendar resources for each of the users of the account.

Comment: Hey DalmTo
Thanks for the idea but i do need to get the list of resources first right ? , as all the employees are under the same account I guess the number of resources shared across will be the same.
I did check that but to check against my list of resources, i need to get them first and i dont have any idea on how to retrieve that list.

Comment: Users list should return user resources the other request you are doing is only going to return calendar resources for a user

Comment: FYI, The alias is literally just typing in the phrase:  my_customer     Also, I read elsewhere on other stack that your actual customer ID will be returned in the API results.  Have not yet seen this,though.

Comment: Thanks @garec 
Now i do have an idea about the api the only problem is that i am getting a bad request response when i test it with google auth online tester.